# How to have a join table with relationship between 3 entities(USER,Organization and Roles)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, mapping

I have a scenerio where one staff can belong to multiple organisation and for each organisation he can have different role. How can i map this in jpa?

**Staff.java**

```
public class Staff {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="STAFF_ORGANIZATION",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="staff_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="organization_id"))
    private Set<Organization> organizations;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
}
```

**Organization.java**

```
public class Organization {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String OrganizationName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="organizations")
    private Set<Staff> staff;
    }
```

**StaffRoles.java**

```
public class StaffRoles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Roles roles;

    public enum Roles {
        USER(100), ADMIN(200);
        private int values;

        Roles(int values) {
            this.values = values;
        }



        public int getValues() {
                return values;
            }
}
```

Can anyone please help me in mapping the roles to the staff. So many staff can belong to many organisation and for each organisation he can have different role.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Using an entity Membership, which would have a ManyToOne with User, a ManyToOne with Organization, and a ManyToOne with Role.

Answer (score 2):

Althought this question is not written clearly I will answer your question based on what I have understood.

Below is an ER-diagram for how your tables might look like.

[image: ER Diagram]

Now you just need to create the classes needed.

1. User.java
2. Organization.java
3. UserOrganization.java
4. UserRole.java

Connect the right instance variables now via ManyToMany and OneToOne to achieve your goal.

EDIT:

After the question has been updated with more specific information, I can aid more in this answer. First make a StaffOrganizationRoles class that will sit between StaffOrganization and Roles. Next, make StaffOrganization sit between Staff and Organization, which means that instead of ManyToMany it will be ManyToOne from Staff -> StaffOrganization, and ManyToOne from Organization > StaffOrganization.

```
public class StaffOrganizationRoles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stafforganization_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private StaffOrganization user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Role role;

}
```

Staff organization class:

```
public class StaffOrganization {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Staff staff;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "staffOrganization")
    private Set<StaffOrganizationRoles> staffOrganizationRoles = new HashSet<>(0);

}
```

I've edited the picture above to represent the new ER-diagram.

Hope this will help you now.

Comment: So if i make the relationship between User and Organization as manytomany then implicitly a Join Table USER_ORGANIZATION will be created. So now how can i map this table 'USER_ORGANIZATION' to USERORGANIZATION entity?

Comment: i have updated my question with my code.. Can you please tell me how can i map staff entity with role?